# Is this probability calculation correct?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics

My professor (in a Computer Science class) stated that if you have $n$ independent "objects" each with probability of failure of $x$, then the probability failure of exactly two is:

$$(x \cdot n)(x \cdot (n-1))$$

I think this is incorrect, because this implies that $(x \cdot n)$ is the probability of failure of one, but taking the case of the coin toss where $n = 2$ and $x = 0.5$ we get that the probability of a "heads" outcome becomes 100%.

What is wrong with this calculation and how can it be fixed?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution, where $n=n,p=x,k=2$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate @MikeEarnest

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect, but not for the reason you think. Given n independent trials, the probability of observing exactly 2 outcomes with probability x is $\binom{n}{2}x^2(1-x)^{n-2}$. $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, so your professor's formulation is incorrect based on the missing denominator of 2 alone, let alone the terms involving x.

This is a really basic topic; I'm surprised a professor of computer science would have written down such a wrong formula.  Are you certain you copied it down correctly?

Comment: You have $n$ drives with annual failure rate $x$. You want to know what the probability is that two drives (cannot recover) fail is within the mean time to repair (assume 1 day). He stated it would be : $(x\cdot n)(x (n-1))\frac{1}{365}$

Comment: @user129393192 ok, so we're dealing with a Poisson distribution, not a binomial one. Even so, his formulation is still incorrect. I'd really advise asking him directly; it seems like he's made a simplifying assumption somewhere but of course none of us can read his mind lol

Comment: I did during the class break, but he just kept asking me where I was stuck and what didn't make sense. I couldn't word it, but it seems like it made sense to him. I really do not understand it and don't know how it would go asking about it at office hours, since it is not his expertise (he often says he is not a math guy)

Comment: @user129393192 "not a math guy", eh? I can't believe I'm saying this, but I'd abandon any hope of clarity and just take it for granted. It's possible that he merely got that formula somewhere else and is now passing it on to you; in any case, it doesn't sound like he's up to the task of deriving it for you. I'm sure of one thing: it doesn't correspond to any known probability distribution, which is generally what you get taught in a class setting. Someone else may recognise it, but I'm at a loss.